# Finding leaf nodes with a specific ancestor

Tags: sql, ms-access, tree

I have a table

```
id  parent_id
1   NULL
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
8   7
9   7
```

which can also be expressed as a tree

```
     1
    / \
  2     3
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
         / \
        8   9
```

I would want to get all leaf nodes that descend from a node with a given id.

E.g.

- given 3, output should be 6, 8, 9.
- given 7, output should be 8, 9
- given 1, output should be 4, 5, 6, 8, 9

Is this possible with Microsoft Access SQL or would a loop of some sorts in code yield better performance?

Comment: There is no "trickery".  Postgres supports recursive CTEs, which is the appropriate solution.  However, you should tag the question with the database you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Removed PostgreSQL from the question and left in only MS Access SQL, as it's of immediate importance. Although if anyone is willing to, I would be also interested in how this is solved in PostgreSQL.